# JavaScript: warning against empty types, null, undefined and NaN

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function `warn` that serves as a light general error handling function which does the following:

- test a variable for a condition (generally `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, but could be `[]`, `''`,etc)
- output a warning if the condition is true (and verbose is on)
- end the function if the condition is true (and fatal is on)

Currently, this is what I have:

```
function warn(thing, thingString, shouldNotBe, fatal, verbose){
    // default verbose
    if (verbose == undefined) {verbose = true;}
    // default fatal
    if (verbose == undefined) {verbose = false;}

    if (
      thing == shouldNotBe || // test for undefined and null
      (isNaN(shouldNotBe) && shouldNotBe != undefined && isNaN(thing)) // test for NaN
    ) {
      message = thingString + ' is ' + shouldNotBe

      if (fatal) { message = '[FATAL]: ' + message}

      if ( verbose ) { console.warn( message ) }

      if ( fatal ) { return true }
      else { return false }
    }
  }
```

This lets me do the following in my code:

```
var myVar
fatal = warn(myVar, 'myVar', undefined, true)
if ( fatal ) {return}

> [Fatal]: myVar is undefined
```

The problem I am facing is JS's NaN:

```
NaN === NaN ---> (false)
NaN == NaN ---> (false)
isNaN(NaN)  ---> (true)
isNaN(undefined) ---> (true)
isNaN(null) ---> (false)
```

So I have to have this ugly conditional (which I could shorten):

```
(isNaN(shouldNotBe) && shouldNotBe != undefined && isNaN(thing))
```

to:

- first test that the variable `shouldNotBe` is not a number (`undefined` or `NaN`)
- test that `shouldNotBe` is not undefined
- test that the `thing` is also `NaN`

So my question is there a better way to approach this problem? The fact that `NaN` **can not** be tested by conditional really throws a wrench in this.

Comment: Have you tried any of the lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isNumber functions? There's a range of them like _.isNaN, _.isNumber, these are very useful for this type of thing. also _.get(object, fieldName, defaultValue) is great when you don't trust data.

Comment: @TerryLennox no, I haven't used `lodash`, (although I have heard of it). I prefer to not use dependencies when possible and for something like this, there really should be a straightforward way to approach it in a general way

Comment: I understand your issue, though I love functions like _.get(..) because you end up avoiding long error prone code that navigates an object hierarchy.

Comment: @TerryLennox I'll look into it further as a long term option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the part `isNaN(shouldNotBe) && shouldNotBe != undefined` to [`Number.isNaN(shouldNotBe)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). You might also be able to use [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) instead of `==`, but then you need special cases for `null == undefined` and `+0 == -0`.